# query multiple items to send to view in node using mssql module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to query multiple tables and pass those values to my view, this is my code which is producing the error.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    sql.connect(config).then(() => {
        return sql.query`select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type`
    }).then(result => {
        return sql.query`select Curency_Code from Currency_List`
    }).then(cur => {
        res.render('newProject', {projects: result} , {currency : curr})
    }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
    });
});
```

Please let me know what i am doing wrong. Thanks is advance.

Comment: can you please add error here?

Comment: Yeah, error messages are not just an inconvenience, they are an invaluable debugging tool.

Comment: This is working for one query      router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    sql.connect(config).then(() => {
        return sql.query`select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type`
    }).then(result => {
        res.render('newProject', {projects: result})
}).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
})  I guess i want to know how do i do multiple queries

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're turning a value from your first query to the variable `result`. However you then make another query and don't retain the value as you lose scope of `result`, you'll want to do something like this.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // I've added a variable here which we will use to save the query
    // result to.
    let projectResult;
    sql.connect(config).then(() => {
        return sql.query`select Project_Type_Desc from Project_Type`
    }).then(result => {
        // Now we save the query result
        projectResult = result;
        return sql.query`select Curency_Code from Currency_List`
    }).then(cur => {
        // We are now outside of the scope from the last block (above), so we use
        // the value we saved in the parent scope (router.get).
        res.render('newProject', {projects: projectResult} , {currency : curr})
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```